# How to get the index of an element (an array of buttons)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

- I have an array of 9 strings.
- I also created 9 UI buttons.

Task:

- when pressing the button `[0]` the line `[0]` appears.
- when button `[1]` is pressed, line `[1]` appears

and so on.

```
using Assembly_CSharp;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;

public class WorldMapScr : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject RoomMap;
    public TMP_Text txtHeader;
    public TMP_Text txtDescription;
    public TMP_Text txtNameRoom_1;
    public TMP_Text txtNameRoom_2;
    public TMP_Text txtNameRoom_3;
    public TMP_Text txtNameRoom_4;
    public Button[] buttons;
    allTxtRoomMap txtRoom = new();

    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(OpenWindow);
            txtHeader.text = txtRoom.headerAndDestcriptionlvl[i];
            txtDescription.text = txtRoom.headerAndDestcriptionlvl[i];
            txtNameRoom_1.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i];
            txtNameRoom_2.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i];
            txtNameRoom_3.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i];
            txtNameRoom_4.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    void OpenWindow()
    {
        RoomMap.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I understand that the operations in the for loop don't matter because there is a "break". I sent this code only for an example, so that you understand what I want to achieve. I also want to clarify. The easiest way would be to just create a few separate methods for each button, but that's completely unprofessional in my opinion. Please tell me how this can be done with an array of buttons. Thanks for any replies.

[image: Buttons]

Added:
Thank you very much for the explanation and code example. Of course, with your help, I managed to run the code, but as you rightly pointed out, because of the for loop, listening and reacting occurs many times. This significantly affected the speed. In the end I have this:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => OpenWindow(index));
        }
    }
    void OpenWindow(int i)
    {
        RoomMap.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log(i);
        txtHeader.text = txtRoom.headerAndDestcriptionlvl[0, i];
        txtDescription.text = txtRoom.headerAndDestcriptionlvl[1, i];
        txtNameRoom_1.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i, 0];
        txtNameRoom_2.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i, 1];
        txtNameRoom_3.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i, 2];
        txtNameRoom_4.text = txtRoom.roomLvlName[i, 3];
    }
```

To be honest, I don't have any idea how I can implement the same without using "for". If you have any ideas let me know. Thank you again. I just put the listener in the Start method and it worked. But I'm still confused: did I do the right thing?
P.S:Delegation is a topic I haven't gotten to yet, but will soon!

Comment: As a heads up, don't add listeners in the update loop like this. You will end up with an ungodly amount of events that all fire after you press the button.

Comment: You stated what you want to achieve but in your code I see no attempt to actually solve that task .. what is your specific issue/question? You already seem to know the index of your button .. `i`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create separated methods for each button. Create one method with an integer parameter, pass this method to every Button and pass it's corresponding number as parameter. Then the appear the line with the m_textList[number] value where m_textList contains your text.

Comment: Thank you! Your thoughts helped me understand a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function with parameters to the button's listener by using a delegation. Here's a small example that shows how it works with an `int`, but this can be applied to any type.

```csharp
void Start()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
  {
    int tempvalue = i;
    buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Examplefunction(tempvalue));
  }
}

void Examplefunction(int i)
{
  Debug.Log(i);
}
```

Note that `i` is saved in `tempvalue`, which is passed to the function. This is done so that it doesn't print the Length of the button array, but rather the correct index that was set at the time.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If you have time, please comment on the updates in my post.

Comment: @NoobGeek the for loop isn't the issue here. The problem is that you are trying to run it inside of the `Update` function. This means that every frame a new listener is added. I don't understand, why you don't simply put the loop in the `Start` function. This way only one listener would be added.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you!